# Double quote in cmd file call

Tags: batch-file

From a xyz.cmd file, I want to call dostuff.cmd file, as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd -abc="def"
```

I put the command between double quotes in xyz.cmd, as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd -abc="def""
```

However, when I try to run xyz.cmd, I get an error message :

'"C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd -abc="def""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried escaping the double quotes around def, as follows:
""def""
\"def\"
^"def^"

But I have the same error message each time.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd" -abc="def"`

Comment: That works outside a function but not inside one. Any idea why that might be? However, though it works, it causes my xyz.cmd file to exit and the commands which follow the one above are therefore not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C:\Program Files\Prog1\bin\dostuff.cmd" -abc="def"

This works for me.
Thanks to user2799037